# Karate execution is skipped in Jenkins

Tags: karate

I have integrated my Karate test cases in Jenkins pipeline. But those are getting skipped with below message.

12:08:57.105 [main] INFO com.intuit.karate.Runner - waiting for parallel features to complete ...

Karate version: 0.9.5

======================================================

elapsed:   0.14 | threads:    5 | thread time: 0.00

features:     0 | ignored:    0 | efficiency: 0.00

scenarios:    0 | passed:     0 | failed: 0

======================================================

To be honest, very intermittently I have observed this issue on local as well  ( once or twice in last 6 months) and it was resolved after cleaning the project and downloading the dependencies again. But this time its troubling me a lot.

Has anyone ever faced it? I see there was an issue with parallel thread execution and it was resolved in 0.9.0 version but I am using 0.9.5 version to run my tests.

Many Thanks,
Abhi

Answer (score 0):

You can see if 0.9.6.RC3 makes any difference, but it sounds to me that it is a very rare occurrence, likely because your Maven pom.xml may be a very complex one. No one else seems to have reported this.

If you can replicate this, we can look at it: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Faced the same issue on 0.9.6R3 as well. =================================================================== Karate version: 0.9.6.RC3 ====================================================== elapsed: 0.20 | threads: 5 | thread time: 0.00 features: 0 | ignored: 0 | efficiency: 0.00 scenarios: 0 | passed: 0 | failed: 0 ====================================================== Let me debug some more from my end, then will see if an issue can be created.

Comment: Hi Peter - I renamed my feature files and it started working. really weird..!! Anyways Now I have another issue -I have maven goal as  clean test -Dkarate.env=dev -Dtest=KarateRunner But during the run variables defined in karate-config.js are not being detected. Getting an error - javascript evaluation failed: ENDPOINT, ReferenceError: "ENDPOINT" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1.
ENDPOINT is the variable defined in config file

Comment: @AbhitanshuShukla follow. the. process :) https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue or you can try asking a new question, but I don't think it will help